Single port ROM: how does the CPU read constant data?
I am looking at different CPU micro-architectures.
Frequently, it happens that the ROM is supposed to contain only instruction data. See below for an example:

In such design, how is the CPU supposed to access constant data stored in ROM ? It seems that it is just impossible. If this is correct, then how is the compiler/linker supposed to know it so it will not try to put data in the ROM ? And how are constant data handled in this case ?
EDIT: I reworded my question below because it was not totally explicit.
Let's suppose that we have a constant data or a literal stored in ROM, but too large to fit in an instruction.
To access that data, the compiler will generate a load instruction containing its address.
How will the CPU handle/execute this instruction ? It will require to do two reads from the ROM at the same time: one for the data, and one to fetch the next instruction.
Does the ROM contain two read ports ?

It's fairly common on embedded systems that you have multiple types of memory (ROM, DRAM, SRAM, etc) that have different restrictions. When you setup your tool chain (or more likely download one setup by the vendor), the linker will be configured as needed to put code/data/etc where they belong. Often times there will be different preprocessor defines as well that let the programmer specify which memory to allocate into.

@user1850479 in such a system, if the user decides to tell the linker to put some constant data in ROM, how do the CPU process a load instruction pointing to this data ? Does the ROM have dual port, so the CPU can read the data and fetch the next instruction at the same time ?

You'd have to check the datasheet for the specific device to see what the access restrictions are and how these things are handled.

@user1850479 actually I am trying to design a CPU for learning purpose, and I'm wondering how to handle the memory management module

Often there is also an instruction that loads data from instruction ROM. This takes two cycles, of course, since the instruction ROM can't load an instruction at the same time.

Most CPU architectures include a way to store data in the instruction stream, such as "move immediate" on register machines, or "literal" on stack machines. If the machine has a Harvard architecture, with separate code and data spaces, sequences of such instructions can be used to initialize data memory.

Let's suppose that we want to access a data stored in ROM but too large to fit in an instruction, for example a character string. The compiler will generate a load instruction containing the address of the data. How is the CPU processing such instruction ? Because at the same time it must do two reads from the ROM : one for the data, and one for fetching the next instruction. Does the ROM have two ports ?

Your question has a diagram of a Harvard architecture machine. Such a machine would have two separate ROMs, one for instructions and one for data. So yes, both accesses could occur in parallel. On a von Neumann machine, the accesses would occur sequentially, so a single ROM could contain both instructions and data.

Oh, I see ! So "data memory" does not necessarily correspond to a RAM, but could be a mix of a ROM and a RAM ? And in a von Neumann machine, the next instruction would be fetched one cycle after the reading of the data ?

Yes. The alternative would be to have a start-up function that initializes data in RAM before the main program starts.

I see. And in the case of a Harvard Architecture, how does the linker know that it must not put data in the program ROM but in the data ROM ? Is it the programmer responsability to not put data in the .text section and to create a ".datatext" section in the second ROM ?

A linker for a Harvard architecture machine would already be aware that there are two separate address spaces, and manage them separately. The naming of sections and their mapping into the address spaces would depend on the conventions used on a specific machine. We're talking generalities here.

(sorry for late answer), does it mean that, for example, the GCC linker for RISC-V is not suited for every implementation of the ISA but is micro-architecture dependent ?

No, the linker is written for the ISA, which doesn't change, even on different micro-architectures. It's up to the micro-architecture engineers to make sure they implement the ISA correctly.

oh ok, I misunderstood the previous comment. When you said "A linker for a Harvard architecture machine would already be aware that there are two separate address spaces, and manage them separately" it doesn't mean that there's a particular linker for such architecture, but there's a special configuration / linker script to write that must fit the architecture, right ?

It could go either way. Some architectures have linkers written specifically for them. There are also linkers that are sufficiently general that they can be configured to handle most architectures via appropriate scripting. But this discussion is wandering far afield from the original question about single-port ROM. Maybe it's time to start a new question. Stackoverflow would probably be the best place to ask about writing linker scripts for different architectures.

In a Von Neumann architecture, ROM would be memory-mapped and thus accessed by the same move instructions as RAM and support the same address modes. Move immediates also may be used to get ROM values.
In a Harvard architecture, the code and data spaces are separated. However, move immediates can still be used for loading ROM constants, as the immediate values are part of the instruction and fetched with it.
More general access to ROM-based constants use a 'bypass' path for values fetched from ROM and stored in registers. An example is the 8051 MOVC, a special instruction which accesses ROM as if it were memory-mapped and loads the value to the accumulator.

I see, I'll have a look at the 8051 architecture, and try to get some ideas from it, thanks ! (sorry for late answer)

The TI TM4C129 series ARM Cortex-M4F based microcontrollers have the option of Execute-Only Protection for the flash. Section 8.2.3.5 Execute-Only Protection of the datasheet contains the following, which recognises the impact on the program:

Execute-only protection prevents both modification and visibility to a protected flash block. ...
Literal data introduces a complication to the protection mechanism. When C code is compiled and linked, literal data (constants, and so on) is typically placed in the text section, between functions, by the compiler. The literal data is accessed at run time through the use of the LDR instruction, which loads the data from memory using a PC-relative memory address. The execution of the LDR instruction generates a read transaction across the Cortex-M3's DCode bus, which is subject to the execute-only protection mechanism. If the accessed block is marked as execute only, the transaction is blocked, and the processor is prevented from loading the constant data and, therefore,  inhibiting correct execution.

The TI ARM Optimizing C/C++ Compiler v20.2.0.LTS has the following option in 2.3.4 Run-Time Model Options which allows the compiler to know not to place constants in the "execute code only" section:

--embedded_constants={on|off}     By default the compiler embeds constants in functions. These constants can include literals, addresses, strings, etc. This is a problem if you wants to prevent reads from a memory region that contains only executable code. To enable the generation of "execute only code", the compiler provides the --embedded_constants=[on|off] option. If the option is not specified, it is assumed to be on. The option is available on the following devices: Cortex-A8, Cortex-M3, Cortex-M4, and Cortex-R4.

While the question is asking a general architecture question, the above example demonstrates how the compilers for microcontrollers may address the problem.

In response to the comment:

So, if my understanding is correct, the linker will put the literal in a dedicated flash memory area. Then how do the CPU access this data while also fetching the next instruction ? It will require to do two reads of the same flash memory module at the same time –
Wheatley

For the example of the ARM Cortex-M4 there are two buses in the Code memory map:

Instruction fetches are performed over the ICode bus.
Data accesses are performed over the DCode bus.

The answer in STM32 I-CODE and D-CODE buses shows a Flash interface which arbitrates access from the ICode and DCode buses to the flash memory. While there is a single flash memory, it has a wider data interface (128 bits) than the ICode and DCode buses (32-bit data bus). Prefetching or caching in flash memory module may hide some latency as a result of accesses from both the ICode and DCode buses.

So, if my understanding is correct, the linker will put the literal in a dedicated flash memory area. Then how do the CPU access this data while also fetching the next instruction ? It will require to do two reads of the same flash memory module at the same time

@Wheatley I have tried to update the answer in response to your comment.

(sorry for late answer) : regarding the link, what does it mean "I-CODE and D-CODE busses cannot access the flash memory independently, they do however access the flash interface independently" ? If my understanding of the schematic is correct, the CPU is "stalled" when accessing the flash through the data bus, meaning that the program counter is not updated during this cycle ?
